# Proof by probabilistic method for coins on chessboard puzzle

Tags: probability, combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, probabilistic-method

**Here's a puzzle I worked through a while ago:**

Alice and Bob are in prison, and the warden poses the following game. Alice will be lead alone into a room with an 8x8 chessboard. The warden will place a coin on each square, either heads or tails up. Any configuration of heads and tails is possible. The warden will then tell Alice that one of the squares is "special". Alice then must flip one coin on the board. The warden then leads Alice out of the room. Now the warden leads Bob into the room. Bob must look at the board, and guess which square is the "special" square. If he succeeds, both are set free. If he fails, their incarceration continues.

There is no communication between Alice and Bob during the game, and Bob cannot see/hear what's going on in the room when Alice is inside. However, they can discuss a strategy beforehand. Also, you may assume the board is oriented in such a way that Alice and Bob can agree on which side is the "bottom".

**My Question:**

Now I'm not going to write the answer I came up with in case anyone wants to solve this for themselves. I want to talk about proving the existence of a solution. The existence of a solution can be re-framed in the following way:

Let $(\mathbb{Z}_2^{64},+)$ be the group where the underlying set is 64-bit binary strings, and operation is bitwise-XOR. Let $e_j \in \mathbb{Z}_2^{64}$ denote the string with $1$ in position $j$ and $0$ everywhere else. Prove there exists a function $f:\mathbb{Z}_2^{64} \rightarrow \{0,1,\cdots,63\}$ with the property that for any $M \in \{0,1,\cdots,63\}$ and any $B \in \mathbb{Z}_2^{64}$, there exists $j$ such that $f(B + e_j) = M$.

My question is, without finding an actual example of such a function, could you prove that such a function exists via the probabilistic method? You have an enormous set of possible functions to be working over, so it seems likely that you could. However my attempts at getting the bounds to work have all failed so far. Any thoughts?

Comment: Warden tells her which square is special, correct? And then she picks whichever square she wants to turn over? So she is signaling to Bob information about the location of the special square?

Comment: @MikeY Yes exactly. In the re-framed version above, $B$ is the initial board position the warden sets up, the warden's "special square" is the choice of $M$ and Alice flipping the coin is the choice of $e_j$ that makes $f(B + e_j) = M$. The idea is that the strategy is Alice and Bob agreeing ahead of time on the function $f$.

Comment: So you want an existence proof via brute force-ish discovering one?

Comment: @MikeY Basically yes. I already solved the puzzle a while ago by explicitly finding a strategy for Alice and Bob. I want to see an argument by the probabilistic method to prove that such a function must exist. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_method